# Bones move up on z axis when dope sheet frame slider moved

Tags: animation

I'm having trouble inserting key frames to create an animation in blender 2.83.

The issue is that when I move the dope sheet slide to the right (increase frame number), then the bones lift out of my character on the z axis as if he died and the spirit is going to heaven lol.

Can anyone say why this could be happening?

[image]

Comment: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Delete question and move to decent forum

Comment: Suggest add more detail and your own efforts to your question body instead of adding *"Unanswered! --->"* to the title, Thanks. This will *"bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in"* (hopefully) and is the gist of the page linked by susu. Also consider that this page is driven by volunteers spending their *spare time* answering questions.